# How do I extract these from a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want extract the assigned values in string.

```
"a=b  xxxxxx c = d xxxxxxxxx  e= f    g =h"
```

Like this IN RUBY using REGEX

```
["a=b","c=d","e=f", "g=h"]
```

I have tried:

```
'a= b sadfsf c= d'.scan(/\w=(\w+)/)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hmmm.Yes, I tried Like this 'a= b sadfsf c= d'.scan(/\w=\(\w+)/). I am not that good at regex

Comment: That's close, the regex needs some refining, and you'll need to map the result afterwards, since you'll either include the spaces or end up with an array of arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"a=b  xxxxxx c = d xxxxxxxxx  e= f    g =h"
.scan(/(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)/).map{|kv| kv.join("=")}

# => ["a=b", "c=d", "e=f", "g=h"]
```

Comment: I think the part before the equals is always a single char (assuming first regex was just missing spaces), although that is not 100% clear. To OP: The bits missing from your attempted regex were: 1) allowing for any number of spaces (using `\s*`) and 2) remembering to capture both pieces of text.

Answer (score 1):

It splits the string with the regex and then it stores it in an array

It then removes the white space around the = sign

```
str = "a=b  xxxxxx c = d xxxxxxxxx  e= f    g =h"
results = str.scan(/[\w]+\s*\=\s*[\w]+/)
results.each { |x| x.gsub!(/\s+/, "")}
```

Comment: You need `x.gsub!` to modify the strings in place, or a map instead of each. If that is fixed, this is a valid alternative to accepted answer, and worth a +1

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for both the catch and complement =)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "a=b  xxxxxx c = d xxxxxxxxx  e= f    g =h"
s.scan(/[[:alpha:]][[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]]/).map{|e| e.delete(" ")}
# => ["a=b", "c=d", "e=f", "g=h"]
```